# How to show user if installer is installing or upgrading

Tags: inno-setup

I am a newbie on Inno Setup.
I learned that it replaces existing files if there are already. It works in my code.
Here, I want to show users that Installer detects the previous installation so would replace the files with some text or message box.

Can you let me know how to do that?

Comment: Yes, similar but I should create a registry key for "Uninstall" before using the code. It would look better if it has much more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I do not get your comment. You do not need to create any registry key. The Inno Setup does that. The code in the question does all that you ask for. It detects an upgrade and shows a message. You just want a different message text and you do not want the "uninstall" code (the `if V = IDYES then` branch).

Comment: I just changed the AppID part in the code. But although there is a previous version Installer doesn't show the text message, and I don't see any registry key under "Software.....\Uninstall". That is a problem.

Comment: With the code below, I can check if there is a previous version or not.  "if RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\MyAppName') then.."

Comment: OMG. There is a weird item in my script. CreateUninstallRegKey=no. I think this caused the code doesn't work in house. Thank you.